# Using "will have" with the past participle

Tags: grammar

I came across the following example from the textbook *Advanced Grammar in Use* by Martin Hewings.

> To say that we think a past situation actually happened, we use *will have* + past participle:
>
> > As it was cloudy, few people will have seen last night’s lunar eclipse.

Why isn't the past simple or past perfect used in the aforementioned example?

> As it was cloudy, few people saw last night’s lunar eclipse.

Comment: Your past simple is used to state a _fact_, and not what _we think_ happened. You actually clearly say that yourself. What is unclear about the difference between "I _think_ that X happened" and "X happened (it's a fact"?

Comment: If I think that situation HAPPENED, doesn't it mean that it is a fact?

Comment: @kacherese Only in the minds of deluded people.

Comment: If what you think happened is a _fact_, you claim to be God or something. If I _think_ something happened, I might be wrong. As @JoostKiefte says, only deluded people will claim that their _opinion_ is _fact_.

Comment: This question belongs on [ell.se]

Comment: @oerkelens I'm not sure it has much to do with "one's thinking," in fact -- it's possibly about the **possibility**. .

Comment: @Kris I believe the grammar book is not far off in stating that this construction implies that the speaker _thinks there is a (high) possibility that something happened_. Of course, that is very different from stating that it is a _fact_.

Answer (score 2):

> Because it was cloudy last night, few people saw the lunar eclipse.
>   Because it was cloudy last night, few people will have seen the lunar
>   eclipse.

In what way is the speaker of the second sentence changing the statement, by using a future perfect?

The speaker is making a kind of *prediction*.  *Time will show* that few people saw it. In the very near future, people will be saying they didn't see it. The future perfect there is a very mild form of "Mark my words".  We have no reason to *expect* otherwise. One could even add "I expect" or "one expects" to the sentence:

**Because it was cloudy last night, I expect few people will have seen the lunar
eclipse.**